# Is there an equivalent idiom for 'raining cats and dogs'?

Tags: traducción, modismos, tiempo-meteorológico

In English, if it is raining very heavily, you could say that it is '*raining cats and dogs*'.

Is there an equivalent in Spanish?

Does Spanish use 'cats and dogs? If not why something different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Llover a cántaros**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7BmGIYa)

> a cántaros
>   1. loc. adv. En abundancia, con mucha fuerza. Llover, caer, echar a cántaros.

being [**cántaro**](http://www.spanishdict.com/traductor/c%C3%A1ntaro) a (large) pitcher.

Also, at least in Spain, [**caer chuzos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=97YDR14) or [**caer chuzos de punta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=97YDR14) and [**llover chuzos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=97YDR14) or [**llover chuzos de punta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=97YDR14)

> **caer chuzos, o caer chuzos de punta**
>   1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Llover, granizar o nevar con mucha fuerza o ímpetu.
>
> **llover chuzos, o llover chuzos de punta**
>   1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Llover con mucha fuerza o ímpetu.

being [**chuzo**](http://www.spanishdict.com/traductor/chuzo) a spiked stick.

Also [**jarrear**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MNS3Y2j%7CMNUQpAt)

> 1. intr. impers. Llover copiosamente.

and [**llover a más y mejor**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWErHxJ)

> a más y mejor
>   1. loc. adv. Denota intensidad o plenitud de acción. Llover a más y mejor.

Comment: That's very interesting; is there a specific reason why those words are used? Is there an etymological link somewhere?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: "cántaro" besides being a large pitcher is also de volumen of liquid it contains; thus "llover a cántaros" would indicate that it is raining heavily. As for "chuzo", when it is raining very heavily, the raindrops can hit hard, as if it were a stick

Answer (score 3):

Besides the examples given above, two observations:

#### *Caer chuzos de punta*

There seems to be a common theme of things falling from the sky point first (*de punta*) as a simile for heavy rain. In Spain the word *[chuzo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=97YDR14)* is found, which the meaning of "stick with a metallic point". In Argentina the same word can be used with this pattern, though it's not so common and it means "small jury-rigged knife". The Portuguese cognate *[chuço](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chu%C3%A7o)*  means "spear" or "pike". Coincidentally, Brazilian Portuguese employs the simile *chover canivetes*, where *[canivete](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/canivete)* means "penknife" (this word [exists also in Spanish](http://dle.rae.es/?id=79bJwVG), though I doubt it's in wide use.)

#### *Caer* [...] *de punta* as an insult in Argentina

On top of the above, there is in Argentina a tendency to replace *chuzos* with obscene or escatological references. On top of *that* there has been an interesting development: since the pattern *caer  de punta* expects  to be a reference to some disagreable object, people in social media are now replacing  by names of public people they dislike (typically politicians). Googling for this I just found an Argentinian Twitter user who, on the occasion of some observations of *Podemos* politician Íñigo Errejón about Argentina's government, tweeted: *"[Están cayendo errejones de punta](https://twitter.com/niunkamas/status/834442247982686208)"*.

Answer (score 2):

The closest ones would be:

- [Llueve a cántaros](https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/llover_a_c%C3%A1ntaros)
- [Llueve a mares](https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/llover_a_mares#Espa.C3.B1ol)
- [Está diluviando](https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/diluviar)

Being exaggerated we could also say:

- Está cayendo la de Dios
- Está cayendo el diluvio universal

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you use expressions like "está lloviendo a cántaros", or "está diluviando", since those are more common expressions than "llover a más y mejor" or "caer chuzos de punta" or "llueve a mares". In fact, if you say something like that in Argentina, you will look like a crazy dude, and with the "chuzo" expression... well, the word doesn't even exist here.

So, stay with "lloviendo a cántaros" or "está diluviando" (or simply "está lloviendo mucho"). It's far more neutral.

Comment: That's the reason I wrote "... **in Spain**...". Additionally, the word **chuzo** is in the DRAE (http://dle.rae.es/?id=97YDR14) though it may not be widely used in Argentina as you state.

Comment: Un argentino entiende perfectamente "llover a mares" porqué he usado esa frase con ellos y no hubo caras se perplejidad. Lo de llover a chuzos, no lo sabía ni yo (que soy de Barcelona). Es curiosa la frase.

Comment: @Laiv: nuncha he oido lo de "llover chuzos": lo encontré en el DRAE. En cambio "caer chuzos" y especialmente "caer chuzos de punta" si lo he oido con frecuencia

Comment: Ya puede ser. Lloviendo a mares tp es muy común, pero mis abuelos la usaban mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers here already, but I'd like to add another way to talk about a downpour:

**aguacero** -- which is an extremely heavy downpour

Examples:

> Me agarró un aguacero | *I got caught in a tremendous downpour*
>
> Está cayendo un aguacero | *It's raining cats and dogs*